# Type casting vs as operator in C#

Tags: c#, .net, casting, as-operator

What is the difference between Type casting and as operator in C#. For example in this code:

```
class LivingThing
{
        public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}
class Parrot : LivingThing
{

}

interface IMover<in T>
{
        void Move(T arg);
}

class Mover<T> : IMover<T>
{
    public void Move(T arg)
    {
       // as operator
       Console.WriteLine("Moving with" + (arg as Parrot).NumberOfLegs + " Legs");
       // Type casting
       Console.WriteLine("Moving with" + (Parrot)arg.NumberOfLegs + " Legs");
    }
}
```

Why the Type casting is not valid in the second situation and what is the difference of those?

Comment: Did you mean `((Parrot)arg).NumberOfLegs`? Both lines are not the same, one refers to `arg` and the other refers to `arg.NumberOfLegs`. Looks to me like a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

- `((Parrot) arg)` cast : either `Parrot` instance or *exception* (invalid cast) thrown. Note, that you should cast `arg` first and only then use `NumberOfLegs`: `Console.WriteLine("Moving with" + ((Parrot)arg).NumberOfLegs + " Legs");` note extra `(...)`
- `arg as Parrot`: either `Parrot` instance or `null` (note you can't use `as` if type is `struct` and thus can't be `null`)
- `arg is Parrot`: either `true` if `arg` can be cast to `Parrot` or `false` otherwise

The last case (`is`) can be used in *pattern matching*, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Moving with {(arg is Parrot parrot ? parrot.NumberOfLegs : 0)} Legs");
```

Answer (score -1):

The type casting is invalid because you should do this

```
 // ((Parrot)arg).NumberOfLegs
 Console.WriteLine("Moving with" + ((Parrot)arg).NumberOfLegs + " Legs");
```

Difference are :

- Type Casting (Explicit Casting): (Parrot) if arg is not a Parrot or a type derived from Parrot. It does not perform any safety checks.
- Operator: The as operator performs a conversion between reference types or nullable types, and it includes a safety check. If the cast is not valid, it returns null rather than throwing an exception. So (arg as Parrot).NumberOfLegs will attempt to convert arg to Parrot, and if arg is not a Parrot, it will return null. If you then try to access NumberOfLegs, you'll get a NullReferenceException.

> Note: It's also a good practice to add generic type constraint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint